# Azure CDN Web Site

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have a web site hosted on Azure (http://mike-ward.azurewebsites.net/). I set up an Azure CDN from the Azure portal that points to (references?) my web site. According to the articles and docs I've read, content is only served from the /cdn/ folder (http://az667460.vo.msecnd.net/cdn/images/favicon.ico for example). However, it also seems to serve the dynamic web site stuff by simply referencing the root (http://az667460.vo.msecnd.net/).

Has the policy changed with regard to serving content from other than the /cdn/ folder? If not, what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Al website content is now available through the CDN, see these new examples:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-websites-with-cdn/

In your site you manage the url, so if a resource is referenced with the CDN url: http://az667460.vo.msecnd.net it will be served from the CDN.

the special /cdn folder isn't required anymore